# Are HP wireless printers really THAT insecure?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, printer, firmware

After a firmware update my HP OfficeJet Pro 8710 refused to print because it detected non-HP cartridges. I found a solution on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0ComGBzJx0). Basically, I just had to download an older version of the firmware, and flash the printer with it with the help of `$ netcat` :

```
$ nc -w ip 9100 < firmware
```

With `ip` being the printer's wireless IP address, and 9100 the port to which send the firmware file.

It worked perfectly, the older firmware got restored, and I could use my printer again with non-HP cartridges.

But that got me thinking : it means that anybody with wireless access to the printer could upload a new firmware to it (and potentially a hacked firmware, for example one that sends a copy of all printed documents to some internet server). Scary !

Comment: If anyone you don't trust has access to your network the HP pronter is the least of your worries.

Comment: So what is the question ?

Comment: Are printers really that insecure?  Yes.  As well as every other device on your network.

Comment: Maybe not quite as bad as you fear. It is possible/probable that the drivers need to be digitally signed or they won't be written out (I believe that is true for some HP printerd - don't know if its all, but signing would make sense here).

Comment: "it means that anybody with wireless access to the printer could upload a new firmware" - By default the printer shouldn't allow that.  You would have to go out of your way to allow connections outside of your network.  The printer automatically downloading firmware from HP is a separate issue.  You can also disable it. **I know my HP printer requires a code, printed on a sticker, in order to access the web administrator page.**

Comment: And it reinforces something I have said over and over: do NOT update a printer's f/w unless you KNOW it fixes a problem you experience. This is especially true for HP who pepper their f/w with nasties.

Comment: @davidgo :  you may be right here. True, the firmware I uploaded through `$ netcat` was an outdated but legitimate one, so maybe it was signed. So yes, maybe after all a tampered firmware would have been rejected due of lack of signature. If you post your comment as answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @hdhondt : I agree 100%, from now on the first thing I'll do after unpacking a new printer is disabling the automatic firmware update. Lesson learned ! HP shamelessly deciding to prevent me from using cartridges I used for several years with the same printer really got on my nerves, I'll probably stop buying that brand in the future. I even wonder if it's legal to make such changes to a firmware!

Comment: @ChennyStar Why buy HP after they screwed you? Brother - while not great are an order of magnitude less evil with their DRM and the quality of their printers at given price points are no worse. Many (most?) in the know have switched due to HP chenanigans with retrospective locking out if 3rd party printers and lease-your-ink schemes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This post is speculation** informed by web searches.  I don't have any HP printers, and I am unlikely to ever purchase an HP printer or (non ink-tank) inkjet printer.

The concern about the printers being insecure is legitimate, and up until 2012 or so this likely was the case, however starting in 2012 HP apparently started digitally signing all their printer drivers - since this printer is newer then that date **it is likely that only HP blessed firmware can be loaded on the printer using the naive above method.**

My postulation stems from a few resources -

1. http://hacking-printers.net/wiki/index.php/Firmware_updates talks about HP printers and says "Firmware can be downloaded from support.hp.com or directly from ftp.hp.com via FTP. 419 files in HP's traditional remote firmware update (.rfu) format and 206 newer ‘HP FutureSmart’ binaries (.bdl) can be retrieved. **The .rfu files contain proprietary PJL commands like @PJL UPGRADE SIZE=…, indicating that firmware updates are deployed as normal print jobs. This has been demonstrated by [3] and caused HP to digitally sign all their printer firmware since March 2012 [7].**"  (Emphasis mine)
2. https://www.jsof-tech.com/unpacking-hp-firmware-updates-part-1/ is interesting but other then the link to the above link does not tell us much.
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cqlmyZ-DQsg shows about downloading a different printer, but if you look through the video it does show a similar download for your printer. It seems likely that the logic is the same - note that at about 2:39 the fle name talks about "appsigned_lbi_rootfs_secure_signed" - which implies some signing is happening.
4. I can't find it again, but I did stumble across a foreign language Youtube video which looks like it uses hardware to bypass this code signing to load arbitrary firmware to the printer - but this requires physical access and partial disassembly of the printer.  I've seen subsequent videos showing that device in the thumbnail but when clicked on talk about ways to revert the change, which I posit came after this video was released)
5. My intuition - code signing has been a thing for a while and the tools to do this have been free and widespread for a long time as well.  HP would definitely know about this technology, and the relative cost to add it to their development pipeline is small, providing significant wins for them.  (better security, and No-One-But-Us control of devices)